# what is the worst-case running time for finding two given vertices are adjacent in Adjacency matrix implmentation of a graph

Tags: graph

What is the worst-case running time for finding two given vertices are adjacent in Adjacency matrix implmentation of a graph? Is that not O(1) as I know the indices of those vertices in the matrix so that I can pick the value in constant time? I read it as O(n^2) in a book. Someone please explain it how to get to this measure.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An adjacency matrix occupies O(n^2) memory, which may be where you're confused. But yes lookup given two vertices is O(1), that's the advantage of an adjacency matrix.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes, your are right. I am confused among those two. after seeing your answer I read the statements of the book once again .... my eyes are open now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

yes. it is O(1) for the reasons stated by you.